# Wordpress Image update filter

Tags: filters

I can't seem to find the filter for an image update.

Right now I have the code below, which works great until someone clicks on an image in the editor and updates it. Then it throws the height and width back in. Is there a filter I can use to stop this? I've tried several to no avail.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to abort depending on the `$_REQUEST['action']`, `$_POST['action']` or `$_GET['action']`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work? Is there not a filter for the image update box?

Comment: Inspect your URl and the ajax requests you're doing. You'll see something like `?action=resize` for example. Then check `if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'resize' === $_REQUEST['action'] ) return $html` before you do the `preg_replace`.